# Building Solaris packages on Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris

One of our projects is a cross-platform piece of code.  We build it on Windows, Linux, and Solaris/SPARC mostly.  Of the 3, we deal with Solaris the least and it's a maintenance pain to keep our SPARC box up and running and in general Solaris administration is not our competency.

A few years back I built a working cross-compiler for SPARC64 on Linux, and that part worked great.  What stopped us from going forward was the last part of our build process, which involves building a Solaris package with pkgmk and pkgtrans.

I was never able to find a Linux solution for building pkg files that can be installed on SPARC Solaris -- does anyone know if one exists today?

Comment: I know people use pkgsrc (http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html) with success on Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally used the tools from Heirloom project: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/
The idea was to cross compile for Sparc on a faster Linux machine and build also the package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that anyone has done the work to build it on Linux, but Sun has released the pkgmk sources as part of the [OpenSolaris](http://opensolaris.org/) source base.

See https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/svr4pkg/ for the source to the entire suite of SVR4 `pkg*` commands, though it may have dependencies on other libraries as well.